# How do I unselect check boxes in java separately without using buttongroup.clearSelection() method?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am programming a game in which the user has to click on check boxes and the result will be calculated and displayed. All the check boxes are working but whenever i put them in a buttongroup to save the time , while running the program, selecting one box unselects the other one.

My code so far

```
 int choice[]=new int[15]; 
 int spots[]=new int[5];
 int score=0;
 public void Generate()  // this method generates random numbers and the user has to guess what they are.
   {
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
         spots[i]=(int)((Math.random()*150)+1);
     }
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
         if(choice[i] >= 0 && choice[i] <= 10 && spots[i] >= 0 && spots[i] <=10 ) {                 
           score=score+1; 
         }
         else if(choice[i] > 10 && choice[i] <= 20 && spots[i]> 10 && spots[i] <= 20) {                 
           score=score+1; 
         }
         // .... till 150.
}
// The problem is here

 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Generate();

        jTextField1.setText("");

        // **what can i put here so that all check boxes are unselected.**
    }
```

I don't mind writing a lot of code.I just don't want to use clear Selection() method. using that causes error.

Comment: So, I guess the question is, what have you tried? `JCheckBox#setSelected` seems to be the way to go. I'd also be interested in know what the error is with `clearSelection`

Comment: @MadProgrammer . When I try running the program, selecting one check box and then trying to select another one causes the one I selected first to get unchecked. Are you saying to use the code like -    jCheckBox1#setSelected();       (this is giving me a syntax error :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for helping tho :)

Comment: Okay, first if all, *"selecting one check box and then trying to select another one causes the one I selected first to get unchecked"* - Yes, that's the correct behaviour of a `ButtonGroup`, it limits the number of selected items to one.  If you don't want this behaviour, then don't use a `ButtonGroup`. `JCheckBox#setSelected` is my way of saying, using the `setSelected` method the `JCheckBox` class (which would translate to `jCheckBox1.setSelected(...)`) - check the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected-boolean-) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Okay, That works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ButtonGroups are made for limiting all buttons in this group for only beeing selected one of them. Good example for this are radiobuttons, where only one radiobutton should be selected and all other ones should be deselected. So just don´t use the buttongroup.